# Rotation of rectangular Slick2d image with LWJGL causing distortion

Tags: java, rotation, lwjgl, slick2d, distortion

I'm trying to rotate a rectangular Slick2d image with pixel size 666 x 333 using LWJGL. I was able to rotate a square image with pixel size 666 x 666 around its center, but the rectangular image does distort during the rotation and this is my problem.

Here is the image I use for testing purposes:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bjr5.jpg

The left window shows the image before the rotation, the right window shows the image how it looks when I rotate it 90 degrees, it's distorted: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGcNB.jpg

Here is my source code snippet for the rotation:

```
float x = 0.335f;
float y = 0.335f;
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(x, y, 0f);
glRotatef(angle, 0f, 0f, 1f);
glTranslatef(-x, -y, 0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

You may wonder why I don't use the function “setRotation” or “rotate” of a Slick2d Image. The reason I don't use this does not matter here, but I simply can't use it in my real project and furthermore I want to do it with gl.

It's the first time ever I touch LWJGL and Slick2d and I need it only for a small part of my project. If you know how to rotate the image like above without the distortion, please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be because:

You are using Slick-2D. `glRotatef` and `glTranslatef` require a Z coordinate. This could confuse slick 2D. Also what is your angle variable? `glTranslatef` translates the position of a quad. With lwjgl 3D this would be used to translate the object. glRotatef uses vector rotation. Try researching vector rotation.

Here is a simple pseudocode formula:

Calculate the sine and cosine of the angle once. Dim cosTheta As Double, sinTheta As Single cosTheta = Cos(DegreesToRadians(Angle)) sinTheta = Sin(DegreesToRadians(Angle)) ' Get the disance between the center and the point. Dim dblDistanceX As Double, dblDistanceY As Double dblDistanceX = (PointX - CenterX) dblDistanceY = (PointY - CenterY) ' Set the default position. ReturnX = CenterX ReturnY = CenterY 'Update with the Y offset ReturnX = (ReturnX + dblDistanceY * sinTheta) ReturnY = (ReturnY + dblDistanceY * cosTheta) 'Update with the X offset ReturnX = (ReturnX + dblDistanceX * cosTheta) ReturnY = (ReturnY - dblDistanceX * sinTheta)

90 degree rotation is extremely simple. Just rotate the quad and rebind texture. If you can't do this, then make a 90 degree rotated texture. Just ask if you want another answer with my 90 degree rotation code. I tried to explain how you could use vectors for 360 degree rotation.